# unable to update statsmodels to version 0.8.0rc1 using conda

Tags: statsmodels, conda

I am unable to update my statsmodels v. 0.6.1 to 0.8.0rc1 using conda (I used conda because I have conda installed).

I have tried several ways:

1. conda install statsmodels (based on http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/). Nothing
   happened, my version stays the same.
2. conda update statsmodels. Still not updated, see below.

   > C:\Users\E245713>conda update statsmodels
   >   Fetching package metadata .........
   >
   > Solving package specifications: ..........
   >
   > All requested packages already installed.
   >
   > packages in environment at    C:\Users\E245713\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3:
   >
   > statsmodels               0.6.1               np111py35_1
3. Uninstalled statsmodels and installed it again, and it still installed the old version 0.6.1.

I am using windows 7 Enterprise.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can only install it, if there's a conda package available. If you cannot find a conda package, use pip instead.

Comment: So, based on http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/, it's saying that we can install it using conda, which I did. But, it's still not updated. I've also tried pip based on the same link I mentioned, and still not updated...

Comment: You can find the source here:`https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/releases and install directly from the source using pip.

Comment: Thanks for the help!, I found a way using pip. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

So, what I did is:

```
pip install statsmodels==0.8.0rc1
```

This works for me. I don't know the conda way...

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue as well. I went a different route. I went to the [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) website. I typed `statsmodels` in the search bar and it brings you to this [page](https://anaconda.org/search?q=statsmodels%20). From here you click the version you want to install using conda and it gives you command line syntax to download it.

`conda install -c taugspurger statsmodels=0.8.0` is the version I installed.